# open -n /Applications/TextEdit.app/ not launching new instance?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

```
$ open -n /Applications/TextEdit.app/
```

per the terminal of my MBPr running Mountain Lion the above will not launch a new instance of text edit.  Instead it just brings open instances to the foreground?

per safari

```
$ open -n /Applications/Safari.app/
```

this works...opens up a new instance of safari each time.

How can I open up a new instance of text edit?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It creates several instances for me, regardless of whether I try with TextEdit or Safari.

Comment: interesting...thanks for the reply and for testing it.